# How to distinguish what format a client requests back to my REST webservice?

Tags: java, rest

I have a Java WebService setup which consumes an xml file and want to be able to produce either xml or json based on what the client requests. I know that this is possible through reading up on Jersey REST methods but it does not show how to extract this information. I have also looked on google all over but can't seem to find any examples of this.

http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features is the site that I was initially referencing which shows that it is possible, I was just wondering if anyone would be able to help me find out how to actually distinguish the client's request. Is it in the html header? body? And if so what is the proper way to extract it?

This is what my method currently looks like, I do not have any issues with connection, just finding out what the client requests as a return type.

`@POST

@Path("getStatisticData")

@Produces ({"application/xml","application/json"})

@Consumes ("application/xml")

public String getStatisticData(@FormParam("xmlCoords") String xmlFile) throws Exception{`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract it using the `@HeaderParam` annotation:

```
...
public String getStatisticData(@HeaderParam("Accept") String accept,
    @FormParam("xmlCoords") String xmlFile) throws Exception {

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the functionality that I was looking for and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

The Accept header in the request is used for the client to indicate to the server what methods it supports.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified a bit more: do you know how I can extract that information so that I am able to return xml if the accept header is "application/xml" and return json if its "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

If the client can set HTTP headers, the proper way to do it is to use the Accept header:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

IF this is not possible, the type requested could be passed in as an argument.

Alternatively, expose two different web services: one that returns XML, one that returns JSON. Each web service would call the same code but with a parameter specifying which format to use.